# replace unicode in javascript usando foreach and charCodeAt

Tags: javascript

Necesito verificar si se pego un unicode y quitarlo del string...

```
    //Trae el array.
    $scope.pasteTitle = function (e){
      var stringUnicode = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
      console.log(stringUnicode);
    }

    $scope.pasteTitle = function (e){
        var clipboardData, pastedData;
        // Stop data actually being pasted into div
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get pasted data via clipboard API
        pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        // Do whatever with pasteddata
        $scope.sanitizeUnicode(pastedData);
    }
    var pastedData =[1];
    function PastedArray(element) {
      var n = pastedData.charCodeAt(e);
      if(n <255){
       replace('');//replace unicode character.
        console.log("UNICODE DETECTADO");
      }else{
        console.log("todo en orden");

        };
    }

    pastedData.forEach(PastedArray);
```

Comment: Por favor, intenta que el título de la pregunta no sea en spanglish.

Comment: Unicode es un estándar de codificación, no un caracter. ¿Que puntos de código estás intentando eliminar? O sino, ¿cuáles están permitidos? Por tu código, parecería que querés permitir \u00 a \uFE, ¿La idea es eliminar letras con tilde o ñ y dejar otros caracteres no imprimibles?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un regex para remover caracteres unicode asi:

```
"mi string".replace(/[\ud800-\udfff]/g, "");
```

Yo normalmente utilizo este en IE11 para deshacerme de caracteres raros que aparecen cuando el usuario pega texto del portapapeles:

```
"pasted string".replace(/[^ -~]/g,'');
```